# Summing values conditionally --code not working

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the code below that I'm trying to use to obtain the number of observation overall and for females, males by cohort, grade, and school year (sy). But for some reason the code is not producing the n values for females and males.

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

```
This is the code I used:
dat %>% group_by(cohort, grade, sy) %>% distinct(id, keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  summarize('n'= n(),
            'n female'= sum(gender=1),
            'n male' = sum(gender=2))
```

[This attached picture shows the output I'm getting from the code I've pasted below that's not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlarN.png)

FYI: my data is structured like this:

| cohort | id | grade | sy | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | "17-18" | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | "18-19" | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 11 | "19-20" | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 12 | "20-21" | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 9 | "17-18" | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | "18-19" | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 11 | "20-21" | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 11 | "20-21" | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 12 | "21-22" | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 | "17-18" | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 10 | "18-19" | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 11 | "19-20" | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 12 | "20-21" | 2 |

Thank you!
--Medjy

Comment: try```==``` instead of ```=```

Comment: ...in `sum(gender == 1)` and `sum(gender == 2)`

Comment: that made things worse-- when I add the extra = it says Error in `summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `n female = sum(gender == 1, na.rm = TRUE)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: cohort = 1, grade = 9, sy = "17-18".
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_summarise()`:
! object 'gender' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: When. I try taking away the quotes, it still gave me the same error message as above

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `distinct`? I'm not sure what it's doing there but it's removing your `gender` column. Using `dat %>% group_by(cohort, grade, sy) %>% summarize('n'= n(), 'n female'= sum(gender==1), 'n male' = sum(gender==2))` should do what you need

Comment: MsFlick, your answer works! I specifically wanted to call out the variables I wanted to summarize. With your code, I can do that while also getting rid of the distinct function. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood the question, this can be the right code:

```
dat %>% group_by(cohort, grade, sy, gender)  %>%
  summarize('n'= n())
```

It's ok?